# Extracting data from a string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have e scenario like this: 
I need to build a jQuery function that takes a string as an input and update the string into another string. 
The input can be one of these:

- `A="0"`
- `A="0, 5"` (basically can be "0, any_other_digits_different_from_0")
- `A="0, 58"`
- `A="58"` (basically any number that doesn't start with zero)

I want the function to updated to:

- if input is option number one (`A="0"`) update `A="--"`
- if input is option number two (`A="58"`) DO NOTHING, leave it `A="58"`
- if input is option number three (`A="0, 5"` update to `A="5"`
- if input is option number four (`A="0, 58"`) update to `A="58"`

Option four can have more than two digits after "0, ".

It seems like this can be done by regex somehow but I am not being able to put anything together that can make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between the cases 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string and take the last value. If zero return `'--'`.

```js
function getValue(a) {
    return (+a.split(', ').pop() || '--').toString();
}
 
console.log(getValue("0"));     // "--"
console.log(getValue("0, 5"));  // "5"
console.log(getValue("0, 58")); // "58"
console.log(getValue("58"));    // "58"
```

A proposal with a regular expression searching for last numbers

```js
function getValue(a) {
    return (+a.match(/\d+$/) || '--').toString();
}
 
console.log(getValue("0"));     // "--"
console.log(getValue("0, 5"));  // "5"
console.log(getValue("0, 58")); // "58"
console.log(getValue("58"));    // "58"
```

Comment: I went with the first option because it is easier to read (at least for me). It works perfect. Thank you.